# orientation issue - ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

my App has several uiViews and set to support both orientations. since my uiViews frames are only part of the whole size of the iPad, so I'm trying to center my uiviews frame depending on how the iPad is held aka orientation. It's is done in this manner in the view controller.m file:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation des=self.interfaceOrientation;

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) //iPad
    {
        CGRect ScreenBounds  = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

        if(des==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||des==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)//ipad-portrait
        {

            ipStPosX=(ScreenBounds.size.width -360)/2;
            ipStPosY=100; 
            return YES;
        }
        else//ipad -landscape
        {
            ipStPosX=(ScreenBounds.size.height -360)/2;
            ipStPosY=100; 
            return YES;
        }
    }
    else//iphone
    {
        UIInterfaceOrientation des=self.interfaceOrientation;

        if(des==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||des==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) //iphone portrait
        {
            return NO;
        }
        else //iphone -landscape
        {
            return YES;
        }
    }
}
```

after launching the app and changing the orientation it will always go to the portrait part, UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait, regardless of how i hold the device.

I saw some old posts that didn't really fit the issue and were confusing or dated so any help here will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is for simply telling iOS that you support particular orientations.  since you want everything but iPhone landscape, you should return

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) //iPad
        return YES;
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation);
}
```

for actually adjusting what you display, you want to use `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` or `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` for actually changing items.  in your case, given that you are just adjusting some iVars depending upon which orientation you are in, i presume you will use the latter.

```
- (void)didRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromOrientation
    UIInterfaceOrientation des = self.interfaceOrientation;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) //iPad
    {
        CGRect ScreenBounds  = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(des))//ipad-portrait
        {
            ipStPosX=(ScreenBounds.size.width -360)/2;
            ipStPosY=100; 
        }
        else //ipad -landscape
        {
            ipStPosX=(ScreenBounds.size.height -360)/2;
            ipStPosY=100; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what i'm doing is changing the initial position of the UIView frame, like: self.svDGrid.frame = CGRectMake(1+ipStPosX, 271*scaleY, 320*scaleY,200*scaleY );      I'm not familiar with the didAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration method can i use the same code as the one i posted for the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation ??  not seem to work. If you can elaborate or share some sample it will be helpful to me

Comment: exactly so.  for doing this, use *willAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:* or *didAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:* .  but to get it to work for all orientations, you still need to answer *return YES;* in *shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:* .

Comment: ok, i've updated my answer, incorporating your code for clarity)

Comment: I used didRotateToInterfaceOrientation as described above  and i'm physically changing my iPad from portrait to landscape it didn't trigger this method. If i used willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration instead it will go inside the method but then again it thinks it's portrait regardless how i'm holding the iPad..  umm any idea?

Comment: do i understand correctly that the code above is for a particular viewController?  if you don't have the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: set up to work this way throughout your code, then one of the parents may prevent one of the children from rotating.

Comment: yes a specific viewController (i only have one viewController.m) and i have the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation  return YES to all orientations. What with the method signature is it duration as you initially wrote or fromOrientation?

Comment: documentation is here: *http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html* .  i fixed the text to be clearer.  willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: has a duration: in its signature.  didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: does not.

Comment: it was signature issue and it's calling the method. However i just realized that i also need to redraw or refresh the frames views with the new variables values so it should be placed with the new location values. any idea how to go about that? or should it automatically should happen.  Hope it makes sense. Again, thanks so much for for help.

Comment: I guess i need to build a method that redraws all UIViews and call it every time the orientation has changed like : [self refreshAppLayout] ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two problems here:

1. Enabling rotation - This can be done by implementing the method below. You should put a breakpoint in this method to ensure its called and you return YES. Please note that this method is only called for those views that are pushed to the navigation bar or tab bar or are part of the window. This will not be called for views that have been added to other views using addSubView method.

   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation;
2. Implementing the above method and not implementing any other method will rotate your view. If it does not, you need to investigate the points I have outlined above. Once your view starts rotating, you need to then play with the autoresizing masks to achieve what you are planning to do. Centering the views should be easily achievable using autoresizing masks. If using XIBs, you can review the resizing behavior from within xcode.